# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate error in eclipse

Tags: android, ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-iot

In android studio code we are using key and trust, as per the document we created bks(emmtruststore.bks) file and pasted in raw folder

We are getting following error during device registration

error logs for android studio

03-30 11:36:11.930 2200-2817/org.wso2.emm.agent I/System.out: URL: https://192.168.4.216:9443/dynamic-client-web/register

```
03-30 11:36:12.135 2200-2817/org.wso2.emm.agent E/ServerUtilities: Error occurred while sending 'Post' request due to failure of server connection
03-30 11:36:12.135 2200-2817/org.wso2.emm.agent E/DynamicClientManager: Failed to contact server
    org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.IDPTokenManagerException: Error occurred while sending 'Post' request due to failure of server connection
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.utils.ServerUtilities.sendPostRequest(ServerUtilities.java:325)
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.utils.ServerUtilities.postData(ServerUtilities.java:151)
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.services.DynamicClientManager$SendRequest.doInBackground(DynamicClientManager.java:144)
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.services.DynamicClientManager$SendRequest.doInBackground(DynamicClientManager.java:132)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.utils.ServerUtilities.sendPostRequest(ServerUtilities.java:307)
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.utils.ServerUtilities.postData(ServerUtilities.java:151) 
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.services.DynamicClientManager$SendRequest.doInBackground(DynamicClientManager.java:144) 
        at org.wso2.emm.agent.services.DynamicClientManager$SendRequest.doInBackground(DynamicClientManager.java:132) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
03-30 11:36:12.135 2200-2200/org.wso2.emm.agent E/AuthenticationActivity: error occurred while retrieving client credentials
```

Comment: Which  product and which URL you have used. You don't provide enough informations

Comment: 03-30 11:20:18.250: V/ServerUtils(18674): Posting 'password=8AjoFA&username=nikhil' to https://192.168.4.216:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey

Comment: Attache the logs in the question. It's not readable.

Comment: Can anyone solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing the API through HTTPS, your client must have it's own truststore. You can use EMM's keystore as your truststore for this purpose. Or else, you can create your own truststore.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "$EMM_HOME/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error
03-31 12:24:30.704 31994-32492/org.wso2.emm.agent I/System.out: URL: https://192.168.4.216:9443/dynamic-client-web/register
03-31 12:24:30.774 31994-32492/org.wso2.emm.agent E/org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.clients.OAuthSSLClient: Error occurred while loading trust store. 
03-31 12:24:30.779 31994-32492/org.wso2.emm.agent E/DynamicClientManager: Failed to contact server
                                                                          org.wso2.emm.agent.proxy.IDPTokenManagerException: Error occurred while loading trust store.

Comment: In MutualSSLClient class                                                  'AuthenticatorFactory authenticatorFactory = new AuthenticatorFactory();
   MutualSSLAuthenticator mutualSSLAuthenticator = (MutualSSLAuthenticator)
   authenticatorFactory.getClient(Constants.Authenticator.MUTUAL_SSL_AUTHENTICATOR, null,Constants.ADD_HEADER_CALLBACK);
   slSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(mutualSSLAuthenticator.getCredentialCertificate(), Constants.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, localTrustStore);'

Comment: In OAuthSSLClient class
KeyStore localTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
inStream =IdentityProxy.getInstance().getContext().getResources().
openRawResource(R.raw.wso2carbon);
localTrustStore.load(inStream, Constants.TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

Comment: You can follow [Generating the OAuth 2.0 Access Token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Generating+the+OAuth+2.0+Access+Token) and see.